# Certificate Authentication Being Cached on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, https, nsurlcredential

So I have an app that makes https requests to a server.  It uses a .p12 certificate and password to authenticate.  Now it currently caches this after the first authentication challenge, and subsequent HTTP requests do get challenged.  I wish to "Logout" and delete the cache so that it will again perform an authentication challenge. I have been looking at various related posts on stackoverflow and other websites, but haven't found a concise answer to my problem yet.  I would rather not include another SDK (such as ASIHTTPRequest) to do this.  Can anyone help me?

Cheers,

Robin

Update:
So to clarify, I have tried

```
NSURLCredential *identityCredential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithIdentity:identity certificates:nil persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNON];
```

I have also tried deleting all the cookies and clearing the sharedUrlCache

Problem identified:

Ok, so problem is NSURLConnection automatically appends the "Connection":"keep-alive" header. Hence making the same request multiple times in rapid (within 10-15 seconds) succession means the connection is still open and therefor no challenge is necessary. Apparently there is no way currently to change this as manually setting this header to "close" doesn't do it .

Comment: Also note, that when I perform NSDictionary *credentialsDict = [[NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage] allCredentials];, the dictionary is empty

Comment: And if I wait for a period of time (ranging from 10-30 seconds), it will again challenge and call didReceiveauthenticationChallenge method

Comment: Ok, so problem is NSURLConnection automatically appends the "Connection":"keep-alive" header.  Hence making the same request multiple times in rapid (within 10-15 seconds) succession means the connection is still open and therefor no challenge is necessary.  Apparently there is no way currently to change this as manually setting this header to "close" doesn't do it